# Able to parse RSS feed file in Java project, unable in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, rss, saxparser

I have a Java Project in Eclipse where I download the CNN technology RSS [feed](http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_tech.rss), then use SAX to parse and get the number of items in the feed.

```
//download file
URL url = new URL(address);
InputStream is = url.openStream();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("newsfeed.xml");

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead = is.read(buffer);
while (bytesRead != -1) {
    fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    bytesRead = is.read(buffer);
}

fos.close();
is.close();

//read file
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();

RSSHandler handler = new RSSHandler();
reader.setContentHandler(handler);

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("newsfeed.xml");
InputSource is = new InputSource(fis);
reader.parse(is);
```

However when I take this code in Android, I get a Parser Exception on the line

```
reader.parse(is);
```

The only code I change in Android is

```
//download file
FileOutputStream out = context.openFileOutput(FILE_PATH, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//read file
FileInputStream stream = context.openFileInput(FILE_PATH);
```

any idea why this happens? or how to fix it?

The exact error I get is a SAXException with the message "At line 1, column 0: not well-formed (invalid token)"

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Use Below url

http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2012/06/android-rss-feed-reader-example.html

RSS Parser with CustomAdapter using AsyncTask